# If A and B are Hermitian Matrices, $\text{tr}(ABAB) \geq 0$.

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, trace, positive-definite, hermitian-matrices, nonnegative-matrices

Can anybody help me with this problem.
If $A$ and $B$ are Hermitian Matrices, then $\text{tr}(ABAB) \geq 0$.

It is easy to show that the trace is a real number, but I cannot prove that it must be non-negative.

Comment: This is just an idea:
You can change the order inside the trace, so you have
$$ \text{tr}(ABAB) = \text{tr}(AABB). $$
For the trace, it holds that if $X$ is positive definite and $Y$ is not negative definite, then
$$ \text{tr}(XY) \geq 0. $$
The product of two matrices is always positive semi-definite, maybe one can show that it is always positive definite for hermitian matrices?

Comment: @question You are not allowed to change the order of matrices like that... The trace is cyclic, but there the story ends.

Comment: @QuantumSpace Yeah you are right, it is only invariant under cyclic permutations, so my idea fails...

Comment: Whilst this doesn't hold for Hermtian matrices, if $A$ and $B$ are both positive semidefinite then the trace is nonnegative.

Comment: in fact it is sufficient for just one of them to be psd, to ensure the trace is non-negative

Answer (score 4):

You need further conditions. Take
$$ A = \pmatrix{1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1},  B=\pmatrix{0 & 1\\ 1 & 0}.$$
Then $AB$ is a rotation by 90 degrees and $(AB)^2=-I$ has trace -2.

Comment: you are right, I forgot the $^2$